# HTML Links are adding an extra path in the href

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

I am currently designing a small website using JSP / Servlets. Tomcat is very picky about my routes.

- My application can be entered throught the path `/Final` (on a localhost I have `http://localhost:8088/Final`).
- My main JSP page is at `http://localhost:8088/index.jsp`. On that page, I have a navbar with several links. On one of those links, the "Home" link, I have the `href` set to `/Final/index.jsp`. When I hover over the link, it shows the links path as `http://localhost:8088/Final/Final/index.jsp`.

At first, I said ok, lets just change the href to `index.jsp`, but when I do that, the link now points to `http://localhost:8088/index.jsp` which will not satisfy the server. Why are links behaving like this? How can I get it to point to `http://localhost:8088/Final/index.jsp` without fully qualifying it?

Comment: You really ought to show the code you were using to create the link.  Otherwise the question is useless to people who might be having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, adding the `.` before the path as in `./index.jsp` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a relative path such as pointing it directly to it's location. I'm not sure if this would work, but try putting `/index.jsp` as the href in your link. This way it's going from your current folder "Final" and going one level down to `index.jsp`.

Comment: That didn't work, but using `./index.jsp` as the href worked fine.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Post your solution as the answer so others who may have the same issue know how you fixed it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to escape your file and specify it again, it worked for me.

For example: `../jsp/index.html`